# Fully Qualified domain name in mysqldb syntax

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

Trying to connect to a hosted mysql instance in a python script and getting an error. From what I've read this seems to be down to be not using a localhost or ip address as the hostname.

Has anyone any guidance as to what might fix this or do I need to look at rehosting my db because the hosts won't supply an IP...code and error below as appendix.

Thanks, Tom

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='dbname.db.1and1.com',
                 user='user',
                 passwd='password',
                 db='db')
```

Error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'dbname.db.1and1.com' (2)")

Answer (score 0):

Try `nslookup dbname.db.1and1.com` to check if you can resolve this domain. If not, then you should consider networking issue but not programming one.If so, try to use IP instead of domain in case that there may be something wrong with your DNS server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I did an nslookup and it wouldn't resolve...will it only work with IPs then? I find that surprising because the likelihood of the hosting service changing the IP associated with the DNS is probably quite high.

Comment: I believe it will work right with IP. But first of all, you have to ping through your destination IP. As time goes by, domain will be more likely to change than IP.

Comment: Hmm I don't agree, a domain is far less likely to change than an IP - either way, I can't ping/nslookup the subdomain, it doesn't resolve to an IP...

Comment: So you mean that you want to connect to a MySQL database which is based on a unreachable host. As I said in the answer, you should fix your network issue first.